# Area not present in an URL generated by RedirectToAction and Url.Action after switching to ASP.NET core 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have an asp.net core 2.2 app that uses Areas. I generate an action URL using `Url.Action("ActionName")`. This generates the url in the following format `<area-name>/<controller-name>/<action-name>`.

I have upgraded to .net core 3 and after the upgrade the generated URLs do not have `<area-name>` part in it anymore, only `<controller-name>/<action-name>` is generated.

I read the changes that were introduced in 3.0 and did not find anything useful.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Code Setup

**Here is how the routes are set up in startup.cs**

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "error",
        template: "{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Error", action = "Error" },
    );

    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "admin",
        areaName: "admin",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
        defaults: new { area = "admin", action = "index" },
    );

    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "identity",
        areaName: "identity",
        template: "{area}/{controller}/{action}",
        defaults: new { area = "identity", action = "index" }
    );

    routes.MapAreaRoute(
        name: "cmsfront",
        areaName: "cmsfront",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Front", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

**Here is how MVC is set up:**

```
services
            .AddMvc(setupAction =>
            {
                setupAction.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Latest);
```

**And this is the Area folder structure:**

[image]

Comment: Did you disable endpoint routing in 2.2?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes I did disable it, but not in 2.2, I disabled it in 3.0. It would not start otherwise, because I have my routes set up using `app.UseMvc(routes => { ... });` but I haven't made any changes to the routes themselves.

Comment: Could you share your Startup.cs and how is the folder structure like in `Area`?

Comment: @Rena I have updated the original question. Nothing has changed since 2.2 except for `EnableEndpointRouting = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. I was defining the first route (for errors) using `routes.MapRoute` and that was causing the problem. I moved it below `routes.MapAreaRoute` definitions and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<a asp-area="AreaName" asp-page="PageName">Link</a>
```

everywhere in your application.
If you are already on a page inside the Area,

```
<a asp-page="PageName">Link</a>
```

does the Trick.

Comment: Well, I was looking for a way to get the area automatically without me having to specify it manually everywhere.

Comment: If you are inside the area you dont need to mention the asp-area. e.g. if you have a link to /admin/logs on the page /admin/overview and the area is /admin, the tag asp-page="Logs" does the trick.
If you are outside the /admin area, you need to specify asp-area="Admin".

Comment: Steinbah, I am trying to generate a link with Url.Action("ActionName"), I am not using a tag.

Comment: I see that, but was is preventing you from using tags?

Comment: I need only URL, not the HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

Change `routes.MapAreaRoute` like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              name: "admin",
              template: "{area=admin}/{controller=Test}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```